# How to write android app backup to public storage

Tags: android

Several apps on my Android phone write their backup files to "Internal Storage/Backup" (like Signal, Podcast Addict and others). This folder `Backup` is next to `Downloads`, `Documents`, `Pictures`, etc.

In my own Android app I want to write my backup file to that same folder. I have been trying to find out how to access that folder in the "android way".

What I have [found](https://sodocumentation.net/android/topic/150/storing-files-in-internal---external-storage) are recommendations to use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, however all examples only always talk about the folders mentioned above, but not `Backup`. There is also no `String` constant in `Environment` named `DIRECTORY_BACKUP`.

To add to my confusion, this method is deprecated with the following message:

> Alternatives such as Context#getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT offer better performance.

However, the documentation of `Context.getExternalFilesDir(String)` contains:

> [...] where the application can place persistent files it owns. These files are internal to the applications, and not typically visible to the user as media.

`MediaStore` seems to be about media like audio, video and images and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is only for existing files (according to its documentation).

Q1: Is the `/Backup` folder the *right way<sup>TM</sup>* to store an app data backup? Should I use [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file) instead?

Q2: How to programmatically access the `/Backup` folder in my **public** storage?

(Q3: why is it called "Internal Storage" in my phone's UI, yet "External Storage" in the (now deprecated) method used to access it?)

Please answer Q2 even if the answer to the first question makes it obsolete.

Comment: Backup is no default public dir hence no Environment variable for it. But you could just use "Backup" there.

Comment: getExternalFilesDir() is a completely different path. Unusable.

Comment: You could use MediaStore to put files in Backup directory.

Comment: There is ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT if you wanna use SAF. Or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. Both require user interaction.

Comment: Q3: for historic reasons. And that method is now undeprecated.

Comment: @blackapps When has it been "undeprecated"? I am using SDK version 31 and there it is deprecated.